# PHP 5.5.27 Opcache not working on Apache 2.4 CentOS 7

Tags: php, apache, opcache

I've using PHP 5.5.27 installed on Apache 2.4 on CentOS 7. Opcache is showing on a `phpinfo()` page as:

> Opcode Caching: Disabled

Yet below `opcache.enable` shows 'On'. I verified the proper `php.ini` is being used (`/etc/php.d/opcache.ini`) and it shows that it is loading up above in the list of loaded config files. I tried replacing `zend_extension=opcache.so` with the full path to the file, but that didn't work either. I even restarted apache after each of the changes.

I feel like I must be missing something simple, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.

Comment: `opcache` is supposedly enabled, but `php.ini` seems to be showing @habiem that it is disabled.

Comment: To clarify, opcache shows enabled but `phpinfo()` is showing conflicting info.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had `zend_extension=opcache.so` in my `/etc/php.ini` file as well as in the `/etc/php.d/opcache.ini`. Removing it from `/etc/php.ini` fixed the issue. Guessing that either it couldn't find the path, or didn't like that it was listed twice.